# SaltStack Plugin Usage in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, salt-stack

Trying to incorporate SaltStack Plugin(https://plugins.jenkins.io/saltstack/) in a pipeline

Plugin is used to send a message to Salt API as a part of the Build step,

sample ***DSL Pipeline*** script is below

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'agent1'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('saltcommand') {
      steps {
        salt(authtype: 'pam', clientInterface: local(arguments: '"sleep 3; ls -la"', blockbuild: true, function: 'cmd.run', jobPollTime: 6, target: '*', targettype: 'glob'), credentialsId: 'b5f40401-01b9-4b27-a4e8-8ae94bc90250', saveFile: true, servername: 'http://master.local:8000')
        script {
          env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
          def output = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/saltOutput.json"
          echo output
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could anyone from the community please answer how to generate *credentialsId* argument for the salt command under *stages/stage/steps  salt()*, did not find anything regarding this from official Salt(https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/) or Jenkins(https://jenkins.io/doc/)?

Comment: the credentials id is the ID of a credential stored in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `credentialsId` refers to the credentials stored in Jenkins. As you are using the `pam` authentication type this will need to be an username and password allowed to access to Salt API.

The [Jenkins documention](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#adding-new-global-credentials) gives you a detailed description on how to add global credentials. The `credentialsId` is the in the **ID** field.

**Note:** By default the Salt API isn't enabled and requires additional configuration on the SaltStack side, see the [Jenkins SalstStack plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/saltstack-plugin#configuration) or [SaltStack](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/netapi/index.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Roald Nefs I have installed the plugin before, your suggestion regarding credentialsID is duly noted.